# VBS Type mismatch CLng

Tags: vbscript

I am using VBScript for the first time as it is the only language that a program can read.

Relevant section of code

```
Dim input
Function printer ()
  input = InputBox("Printer", "Input Required")
  printer = input
End Function
```

The software then calls the value of 'printer', and everything works fine when I input numbers, but if I try any text, it throws the below error message

> Error: 13, Type mismatch: 'CLng'
>   in the line:

Comment: Well if this unknown software expects and only accepts `CLng` to work there's little else to do then give it numbers. What are you trying to achieve by feeding it text strings?

Comment: In what line? There is no `CLng()` call in the code you posted.